# wso2 appfactory 2.1.0 wmware image

Tags: wso2, factory

I have found vmware image of wso2 appfactory. The latest I have found is wso2appfactory-vm-1.0.0_alpha1.zip 21-Mar-2013.
As I know from user guide: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AF210/Installing+On-Premise
The latest version is 2.1.0

Is there any wmware image of appfactory of version 2.0.0 or 2.0.1?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a VMware image exists (would be good if someone created it).

If what you are looking for is just kicking the tires and seeing App Factory in action, you can do so with the -as-a-service version of App Factory: [WSO2 App Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/app-cloud).

Also, there are quite a few [YouTube videos of App Cloud in action](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLp0TUr0bmhX5R0a_oVGdDa-tHGvPEkWne).